# How can I keep CSS3 text-shadow from overshadowing adjacent letters?

Tags: webkit, css

I am using a text-shadow effect on text that is rendered using WebKit. It works, but not well. I have white bolded text with the following setting for the text-shadow:

```
text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0px 0px 10px;
```

You can see the unintended effect [here](http://www.stroke7.com/zoomed.png) (zoomed for detail).

You can see the shadow going over the previous letter, turning it gray.
By the way, I've also attempted this using a straight RGB value for the color, so it's not an rgba()-related issue.

Have I done something wrong or is this expected behavior?

Mike

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the following workaround seems to fix the issue:

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 0.1px transparent;
```